# Consume a Java REST service from .NET not returning data

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

In the app I working on, is being developed on C# and .NET framework 4.0. This app calls a REST service to get data. The data returned are in xml format.

During the first httpwebrequest, the respose comes as 302 [Found] and the response header location contains the same url initially requested with some sso info added. I created the second request using the first response's new location and added cookies to the second request. In the second response, I got 200 [OK] status, but the response stream comes as html listed below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;about:blank">
    </noscript>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
   <META  HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;url=http://dev.website.org:80/Workspace/app/file/getfilelist">
   </HEAD>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here's the code i used.

```
private static string GetFileList()
{
    try
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://dev.website.org/Workspace/app/file/getfilelist");
        string Parameters = "id=79&pagesize=10";

        //First web-request to get the authentication 
        HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        request1.Credentials = (NetworkCredential)System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

        request1.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request1.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parameters);

        request1.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request1.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        request1.Method = "POST";

        Stream dataStream = request1.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request1.GetResponse();

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
        {
            this.Url = new Uri(uri, response.Headers["Location"]).ToString();
        }

        //second web-request to get the data
        HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(this.Url);
        request2.Credentials = (NetworkCredential)System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        request2.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
        request2.Accept = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        AddCookies(request2, response);

        CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        foreach (Cookie cookie in response.Cookies)
        {
            cookieContainer.Add(cookie);
        }

        request2.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
        response.Close();
        request2.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        byte[] bytes1 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parameters);

        request2.ContentType = "application/xml";
        request2.ContentLength = bytes1.Length;
        request2.Method = "POST";

        Stream dataStream1 = request2.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream1.Write(bytes1, 0, bytes1.Length);
        dataStream1.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response1 = (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();
        if (response1.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream responseStream = response1.GetResponseStream();
            string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        //
    }
}

private static void AddCookies(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < response.Headers.Count; i++)
    {
        string name = response.Headers.GetKey(i);
        if (name != "Set-Cookie" || name != "WWW-Authenticate")
            continue;
        string value = response.Headers.Get(i);
        foreach (var singleCookie in value.Split(','))
        {
            Match match = Regex.Match(singleCookie, "(.+?)=(.+?);");
            if (match.Captures.Count == 0)
                continue;
            response.Cookies.Add(
                new Cookie(
                    match.Groups[1].ToString(),
                    match.Groups[2].ToString(),
                    "/",
                    request.Host.Split(':')[0]));
        }
    }
}
```

Please help and guide me to fix this code. I'm expecting a xml data from the second response. I'm not much familiar with httprequest and httpresponse code. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: See the line `<META  HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;url=http://dev.website.org:80/Workspace/app/file/getfilelist">` You need one more navigation.   http://www.metatags.info/meta_http_equiv_refresh

Comment: I did one more navigation, but got exactly the same html output.

Comment: FYI. when I tested the REST call in chrome Post Man, the first call returned 302 and second call returned 200 and expected xml data. Am I missing something in the code